# pdfTeX font expansion error - \SetExpansion in microtype package

Tags: pdftex, microtype, font-expansion

I am trying to hammer in some stacked matrix notation to fit the paragraph by shrinking the font. To do so I am using the `\SetExpansion` option from the `microtype` package. But pdfTeX is spitting out this error every-time:

```
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): using fonts with different step of expansion i
```

I have provided one such instance in the MWE below. The text will be out of place when the MWE is run as is. On un-commenting the the `microtypecontext` part the error pops up.

```
    % START PREAMBLE
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}

%Required math packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand\vect[1]{\bm{#1}}%bm{#1}

%For experimenting
\usepackage{verbatim}

%Document and typesetting
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

%Microtyping
\usepackage{microtype}

\SetExpansion
[ context = sloppy,
    stretch = 0,
    shrink  = 100,
    step    =  5  ]
{ encoding = {OT1,T1,TS1,OML,OMS,OMX,U} }
{ }

% END PREAMBLE

\begin{document}

To proceed forward, we first write the equation system in the equation compactly. To do so, define the following ($S$ x 1) vectors of vertically stacked propensities, count outcome indices, observed count outcomes, and combined error terms $\left[ {\eta_{qj}^*\,\,( = {v_q} + {u_{qj}} + {\omega_{qs}} + {\varepsilon_{qjs}})} \right]$;
$\vect{y}_{qj}^* = (y_{qj1}^*,{\text{ }}y_{qj2}^*,\dots,{\text{ }}y_{qjS}^*)'$,
$\vect{y}_{qj}^{} = (y_{qj1}^{},{\text{ }}y_{qj2}^{},\dots,{\text{ }}y_{qjS}^{})'$,
$\vect{m}_{qj}^{} = (m_{qj1}^{},{\text{ }}m_{qj2}^{},\dots,{\text{ }}m_{qjS}^{})'$, and
${\vect{\eta }}_{qj}^* = (\eta _{qj1}^*,{\text{ }}\eta _{qj2}^*,\dots,{\text{ }}\eta_{qjS}^*)'$.

\begin{comment}
{\microtypecontext{expansion=sloppy}%
To proceed forward, we first write the equation system in the equation compactly. To do so, define the following ($S$ x 1) vectors of vertically stacked propensities, count outcome indices, observed count outcomes, and combined error terms $\left[ {\eta_{qj}^*\,\,( = {v_q} + {u_{qj}} + {\omega_{qs}} + {\varepsilon_{qjs}})} \right]$;
$\vect{y}_{qj}^* = (y_{qj1}^*,{\text{ }}y_{qj2}^*,\dots,{\text{ }}y_{qjS}^*)'$,
$\vect{y}_{qj}^{} = (y_{qj1}^{},{\text{ }}y_{qj2}^{},\dots,{\text{ }}y_{qjS}^{})'$,
$\vect{m}_{qj}^{} = (m_{qj1}^{},{\text{ }}m_{qj2}^{},\dots,{\text{ }}m_{qjS}^{})'$, and
${\vect{\eta }}_{qj}^* = (\eta _{qj1}^*,{\text{ }}\eta _{qj2}^*,\dots,{\text{ }}\eta_{qjS}^*)'$.}
\end{comment}

\end{document}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The problem seems to be the relation and binary operator (where an equation can insert a line break). `$y=z$` gives an error, but `$y\mathrel{=}z$` and `${y=z}$` works. But I can't tell you if this is a pdftex problem or a microtype problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug in `microtype`, which neglects to set up the math fonts anew after the change of context; therefore you get a mixture of fonts with the normal settings and those with sloppy settings within one paragraph, which `pdftex` does not allow.

Until the package is updated, you can fix it by adding these lines after loading `microtype`:

```
\makeatletter
\MT@addto@setup{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\microtypecontext[1]{%
    \MT@setup@contexts
    \let\MT@reset@context\relax
    \let\glb@currsize\@empty % <- added 
    \setkeys{MTC}{#1}%
    \selectfont
    \MT@reset@context
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: So this goes into the preamble?

Comment: @RazorXsr Exactly.

Comment: One quick question - can I use different expansion context say Sloopy1 - where shrink is 100 and Sloppy2 - where shrink is 50 - in the same document applied on the math font? As in can the math font be shrunk to different scales in different places within the same document?

Comment: @RazorXsr Yes, that's possible, as long as you don't mix the contexts within one paragraph.