# LuaTeX error (font expansion): font has been expanded with different expansion step

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype, font-expansion

I am suddenly getting the following error when trying to compile my document with LuaLaTeX and my simple question is: what does it mean?

`LuaTeX error (font expansion): font has been expanded with different expansion step.`

I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82610/16657) as a possible solution but it did not change anything.

I am saying "suddenly" because when I was compiling the same document on another machine last night, it worked fine. The only possible difference I can come up with is that the other machine might not have had the very latest version of `fontspec` or `microtype`, but the one where the error occurs does (via MiKTeX).

At this point, I don't want to create a mimimal code example, I'd just like to understand what that error means so I can try and trace it. But here is how I load the relevant packages:

```
\usepackage[
  activate={false,nocompatibility},
  final,
 ]{microtype}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\setmainfont[Microtype,Ligatures=TeX,Renderer=Basic]{Times New Roman}
```

I should add that the error disappears when I deactivate the microtype package.

And this is the relevant part of the logfile:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU2/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 4.
 ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd"
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
luaotfload | load font: auto-selecting default features for script: dflt (was l
atn)
luaotfload | load font: font family='timesnewroman', subfamily='regular' found:
 times.ttf
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 4.
Package microtype Info: Generating PDF output.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
Package microtype Info: Automatic font expansion enabled (level 2),
(microtype)             stretch: 20, shrink: 20, step: 1, non-selected.
Package microtype Info: Using default expansion set `basictext'.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of kerning.
Package microtype Info: Loading generic settings for font family
(microtype)             `TimesNewRoman' (encoding: EU2).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.

! LuaTeX error (font expansion): font has been expanded with different expansio
n step.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.4 \begin{document}




Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 31786 strings out of 495011
 125171,1144653 words of node,token memory allocated 1001 words of node memory still in use:
    nodes
   avail lists: 1:2,2:29,3:1,4:9,5:2,6:2,7:1,9:1,11:1
 34213 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+200000
 31 fonts using 6322279 bytes
 65i,1n,95p,886b,696s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82637/7674), you should not mix `microtype`'s interface with that of `fontspec` (resp. `luaotfload`). Either use:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[activate,final]{microtype}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Renderer=Basic]{Times New Roman}
```

or:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\setmainfont[Microtype,Ligatures=TeX,Renderer=Basic]{Times New Roman}
```

(In your case, `fontspec` wants to expand the font with a `step` of 5, while microtype uses a `step` of 1, which causes the error.)